# WPF - how to go to new TextBlock line inside wrap panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<ListViewItem Height="100" Width="600">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Image Source="Resources/asus.jpg" Width="200"/>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Height="20" Text="Asus prenosnik X540LJ-DM289DB" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="1" Height="75" Text="Prenosnik Asus X540LJ-DM289DB se ponaša z 39,5 cm (15,6'') velikim zaslonom, 8 GB pomnilnika, 1 TB HDD diskom, procesorjem Intel Core i5–5200U, grafično kartico Nvidia GeForce GTX 920M in operacijskim sistemom Windows 10."/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
```

I am doing an assignment with WPF. I have to create a "web shop". And I need to have a listview of articles as listviewitems. I added images and article names, but when it comes to article descriptions I want the textblock to go in next line if possible. Couldn't find similar problems on here. Thanks in advance.

[It would be even better if I could have the description below the article name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0mMA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the TextBlock "go in next line if possible" a.k.a "Text Wrap" you need to set the TextWrapping property to "Wrap".

And if you would like to have the description below the article name, you cannot do that with WrapPanel. Here is a solution using Grid;

```
<ListViewItem Height="100" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Image  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="Resources/asus.jpg"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Bold" Height="20" Text="Asus prenosnik X540LJ-DM289DB" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="9" Height="75" Text="Prenosnik Asus X540LJ-DM289DB se ponaša z 39,5 cm (15,6'') velikim zaslonom, 8 GB pomnilnika, 1 TB HDD diskom, procesorjem Intel Core i5–5200U, grafično kartico Nvidia GeForce GTX 920M in operacijskim sistemom Windows 10."/>

    </Grid>
</ListViewItem>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will rather use the first option as there's less XAML to it since I'll have to add listviewitems with C# in the next task. I think it would be more complicated.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are about to make mistake. Are you going to fill the listview's items manually by C# code? You should take a look at databinding datatemplates and listview binding topics @Yanketz

Comment: There are already going to be items in the listview. But when I click one of the filters, new items should pop up. And it says in our instructions that the content that you add should be statically defined in C# code. How do I do that by the way? Let's say with the second solution you showed me.

Comment: @Yanketz take a look at here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149768/c-sharp-how-to-add-images-from-folder-to-array-and-display-them-in-listview?noredirect=1#comment73382929_43149768 I would love help in this thread 
@Hasan Ayan