# C# - how to add images from folder to array and display them in listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

```
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"Resources/", "*.jpg");
lvDataBinding.Items.Add(list[0]);
```

So the folder Resources contains several images that I want to add to an array so I can use them in an easier way.

I need to display them in a window (each one when a different listviewitem is selected).

I would like to know if I can also store them in a class alongside the ListViewItem name and description. So I can do like:

```
Article article1= new Article();
article1.Name = "Article name";
article1.Description = "Long article description etc etc";
article1.Image= images[0];
lvDataBinding.Items.Add(artikel1);
```

And then class would be something like this I guess?

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
    public Image? Image { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Naziv;
    }
}
```

P.S.: I respect all suggestions on how I could do this on another better way. Im sure there are better ways, but I am doing a college assignment and I'm limited on time, also my teacher suggested to "transfer" objects into new windows.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a `ViewModel` with a `ICollection` property and use this property as `ItemsSource` for your `ListBox`.

Comment: Can you go more into detail please? I don't quite understand. Also, I have ListView not ListBox.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can do that. But, you'll have to be more specific with your question. I don't think a simple "yes" answer helps you out much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the path of the image using `string` property. Please refer to the following sample code.

**Code:**

```
public class Article
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
...
string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(@"Resources/", "*.png");
List<Article> items = new List<Article>();
foreach (var path in list)
{
    items.Add(new Article()
    {
        Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path),
        Path = path
    });
}
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvDataBinding" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<Image Source="{Binding SelectedItem.Path, ElementName=lvDataBinding}" Stretch="None" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How would I change the array of paths if I have .jpg and .png ? Also how do I choose which path to set? Im assuming in the row "Path = path" it would be something like "Path = picture.png" ?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand. Each Image has a full path that specifies the directory and name of the file.

Comment: Give me an example how I would use a picture "asus.jpg" in the code above. Where do I put it.

Comment: Change ".png" to ".jpg" and put it in the Resouces folder like you did before?